# express req body empty in contact form

Tags: express, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer to achieve myself sending emails from contact form.
My app.js looks like this

```
    app.post('/jobs/join-us', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body); //to return body
  const output = `


      <p>You have a new message from contact form.</p>
      <h3>Contact Details</h3>
      <ul> 
        <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
        <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
      </ul>
      <h3>Message</h3>
      <p>${req.body.message}</p>
    `;
  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: 'xx', // generated ethereal user
      pass: 'xx',
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  });

  // setup email data with unicode symbols
  let mailOptions = {
    from: 'xx', // sender address
    to: 'xx', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Contact Request', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
    html: output // html body
  };

  // send mail with defined transport object
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.end("error");
    } else {
      console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
      //console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
      res.sendStatus(200);
    }
  });
});
```

Could anybody help me? I also try something like console.log(req) before const output but that didnt' return me anything viable.

This is my contact form itself, the POST request returns 200.

```
       <div class='input-wrapper'>
<input class="flying-label-input" type="text" name="job_form[role]" id="job_form_role" />
<label class="flying-label required" for="job_form_role">Role</label>
</div>
<div class='input-wrapper'>
<input class="flying-label-input" type="text" name="job_form[email]" id="job_form_email" />
<label class="flying-label required" for="job_form_email">E-mail</label>
</div>
<div class='input-wrapper'>
<input class="flying-label-input" type="text" name="job_form[phone_number]" id="job_form_phone_number" />
<label class="flying-label" for="job_form_phone_number">Phone number</label>
</div>
<div class='input-wrapper'>
<label class="label required" for="job_form_cv">CV (PDF)</label>
<input type="file" name="job_form[cv]" id="job_form_cv" />
</div>

<div class='input-wrapper-space-top'>
<input type="hidden" name="job_form[referer]" id="job_form_referer" />
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit Job Application" class="btn-round btn-primary" />
</div>
```

My app.js middleware functions:'

```
const express = require('express')
var app = express();
var path = require('path')
const nodemon = require('nodemon')
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Static folder
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: can you insert an error-catching statement before the console.log like this: `if (!req.body) console.log("form error, body not present");` and tell me what you get in your terminal. Also, can you test `req.body.name` instead of `req.body`?

Comment: Hey, i inserted code like this: `app.post('/jobs/join-us', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body) console.log("form error, body not present");
  console.log(req.body);` the error-catching seems to be returning nothing related to errors, the `console.log(req.body);` returns {} which means it's empty? I believe. @rags2riches

Comment: Are you parsing your form with a `body-parser`? Can you share your middleware functions before `app.post` please. You got to populate the req.body object with a `body-parser`, with an express built-in parser or `multer`.

Comment: Yeah, i am using body-parser.
Here is my middleware functions
`const express = require('express')
var app = express();
var path = require('path')
const nodemon = require('nodemon')
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


// Static folder
app.use(express.static('public'))



app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json())`

Comment: please update your question with the code added rather using code in the comment section. It's better to visualise. OK change the `extended: false` to `extended: true` inside your body-parser middleware.

Comment: Will do next time, seems to be still returning a empty response on body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `req.body` is by default `undefined` so the fact that you get an empty object means that you are not populating the `req.body` with a `body-parser` and/or `multer`. This is also supported by the fact that the error-catching `if statement` does not return an error in the console so the req.body is there and it is an empty object. Try the following express middleware before your app.post and update the app.post as follows:

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer'); // v1.0.5
var upload = multer(); // for parsing multipart/form-data

app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/jobs/join-us', upload.array(), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json(req.body);
});
```